# React, proxy to websocket from package.json get local machine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, proxy

On AWS ec2 instance I have 2 projects react and nodejs

Due to specific of server I can't connect toc socket by it's ip, but...

I'm trying to use localhost from react package.json proxy, but it's not working. React trying to get :3334 port on my local machine

```
"proxy": {
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000"
    },
    "/socket.io": {
       "target": "http://localhost:3334",
        "ws": true
    }
  }
```

React on port 8000, nodejs on port 3000, socket should be listened on port 3334. I implement connection to nodejs, but with this ws. Can't understand what an I doing wrong

in react:

```
const socket = openSocket("http://localhost:3334");
```

On other instance or local machine everything works fine, with ip, but I really need this localhost connection.

Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I define in react io socket strictly to localhost. Solution:

```
const socket = openSocket();
```